# What is the difference between registering services using Instance() and ImplementedBy() methods in Castle Windsor?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I am using castle windsor as IoC in my web application.

And when I register my service as following:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IRequestService>().ImplementedBy<RequestService>().LifestyleScoped());
```

It resolves it as transient lifestyle(for each time I resolve RequestService it gives me new instance)

And when I register it as following:

```
var requestServiceInstance = new RequestService();
container.Register(Component.For<IRequestService>().Instance(requestServiceInstance).LifestyleScoped());
```

It resolves RequestService as singleTon(it does not release it after scope finishes).

My question is what is the difference between the two ways of registration?

Answer (score 1):

The `Instance` method tells Windsor that you take responsibility for the lifetime of the service. It will return always the single one instance you have created. So `LifestyleScoped` doesn't apply here. Use `UsingFactoryMethod` if you want to Windsor take care about lifetime and you still need to control creation of your service.

```
container.Register(Component.For<IRequestService>().UsingFactoryMethod(() => new RequestService()).LifestyleScoped());
```

Comment: Why  it resolves RequestService as transient despite of inside my owin middleware I begin new scope and after request is finished I dispose it

Comment: @SimpleCode, not sure what you mean. You have to provide your code.